# Is passing `user_id` in every view is good ( safe ) or bad?

Tags: python, django, django-views, userid

I am Building a BlogApp and I was afraid of thinking about the passing `user_id` in every view is Bad or Not.

Because i am passing `user_id` in almost every of my views like :-

views.py

```
1.    def new_blog_post(request,user_id):

2.    def open_blog_post(request,user_id):

3.    def all_blog_posts(request,user_id):

4.    def user_profile(request,user_id):

5.    def delete_blog_post(request,user_id):
```

Above -----^ are all the views in my app. I am passing `user_id` in all my views and others.

**Question**

Is it good to having `user_id` in every `view` ?

**What have i tried**

I tried in many websites and searched about it BUT i found nothing on this Topic.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Why do you need the `user_id`. If this is the logged in user, you can use `request.user`.

Comment: I was having problem problem in accessing the `id's` then i declared the `user_id` in every view. BUT everything is working fine. So i was just asking that is it `good` or `bad`.

Comment: All the views are working fine. They are doing their work as i want them to do.

Comment: As stated above you can get the current user by `request.user`. As of your question of if it is good or bad, I would consider it bad as the user sees a number in the url without reason.

Comment: I completely agree with you with the `number in url statement` BUT i think this is not a big issue to consider. Is there something that will not be safe ( I mean in hacking ) ?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no problem with this. Maybe it isn't the most beautiful thing to read but I think you're fine with this.

If you aren't sure than do something like this:

```py
1.    def new_blog_post(request, user_id_1):

2.    def open_blog_post(request, user_id_2):

3.    def all_blog_posts(request, user_id_3):

4.    def user_profile(request, user_id_4):

5.    def delete_blog_post(request, user_id_5):
```